# Files from xournal don't print properly

Tags: printing, pdf

Please read all of this. The story gets interesting at the end. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I used xournal to fill in a form. It worked beautifully (or so I thought).
I exported it as a pdf. Evince (document viewer), xournal, okular, and gimp 
all showed the file just the way I want it, but when I printed from any of those, the
print preview looked fine, but all I got on the paper was the annotation that I added!
I was printing to an HP 722C Deskjet. I need to send  in the 
form (by snail mail) soon, so I put a new ink cartridge in my HP PSC 1410v, and the
file printed fine! (I had been using the 722C because the 1410 had run out of ink).
I hope someone can tell me what is going on 
and (for future reference) how I can print the document on the 722 C.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you want a colour copy or a black and white copy? If black and white, try by making the image black and white in `gimp` and print the image from there (from `gimp`), or save it as a `jpg` or `png` file, and print that file from some program, if you see 'everything' via that program's print preview.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I changed "Color Mode" from "Color" to "Grayscale" and now everything prints (in black and white) as it should.